# Elasticsearch pagination and limit max number of pages

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

We want to filter products, by search term, category, price, location, and a few more.

In Elasticsearch deep paging is problematic, but if we limit to 20 items per page and max number of pages to 100, will be this ok?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. That is ok as long from+size is below 10000 (default limit)

Answer (score 1):

> Note that from + size can not be more than the index.max_result_window
>   index setting which defaults to 10,000. See the Scroll or Search After
>   API for more efficient ways to do deep scrolling.

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html